# Overwriting default attribute types with Styled Component `.attrs` and Typescript

Tags: typescript, styled-components

In previous versions of Styled Components I've been able to override default attribute types for convenience using the `.attrs` function.  [Here's a minimal working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-gxegjz?file=index.tsx).

In the current version, this causes Typescript to error - [see here for an updated example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-8w5w8c?file=index.tsx).

Is it possible to do what I'm trying here, or is it bad practise and deliberately prevented now?